# Pipe seperated params in URL

Tags: apex

I am passing Id's as pipe seperated params in URL and want to pass the params to salesforce reports 
e.g String param_ID_url = '701K00000002MtxIAE|701K00000002Mz9IAE';

when I try to pass to the button using Action global variable the url gets encoded and shows up as : 
701K00000002MtxIAE%7C701K00000002Mz9IAE

Is there any way to stop this and let the | be as | symbol in the URL. I tried using substitute in the button code to substitute '%7c' with '|' still no lucj :(

Please guide me on how to make the | pass as pipe than encoding to %7c

button code:

```
https://www.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/Composer.aspx?
SessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}
&ServerUrl={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_210}
&id={!Campaign.Id}
&TemplateId=a25K0000000D6wF
&FP0=1
&ReportId=00OK0000000FaWF?**pv0={!substitute(String param_ID_url,'%7c','|') }**
&DS7=0
&OCNR=1
```

Comment: I don't think you can change the URL encoding to use your pipe, as that's done on server side. Adjust your code on the other side to split the Id's based on the encoded delimiter (%7C)

Comment: I am passing the ID to the report :( so i cannot seperate it :(

Comment: Are you sure you can pass multiple ID's in a single query?

Comment: i pass muliple ids as url params to report where pv0 represets the first filter of the report.

Comment: I think they need to be comma separated rather than pipe as per this example :
http://acertiscloud.screenstepslive.com/s/manuals/m/invoice_it/l/80749-how-to-configure-conga-composer

Comment: is there any formula/ functions in the report to substitue/ urldecode the input param passed to the report??

Comment: nope i tested comma seerated and conga support suggested to use pipe seperated, I tested the URL with pipe and the reports is loading with the right data taking the ids as params

Comment: Then what's the problem if the reports are working? :)

Comment: You can't pass pipes in a URL as it will be encoded before passing it through. For multiple params to a report , use ?pv0=value1&pv1=value2

Comment: techtrekker i need to dynamically construct the pv values in the constructor and use in the page which sounds a lil pain , but looks like thats the only solution. I will accept that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

As shown on this tutorial:

http://acertiscloud.screenstepslive.com/s/manuals/m/invoice_it/l/80749-how-to-configure-conga-composer

your Id's should be comma separated as oppose to pipe.

Comment: comma seperated on pv0 params will break the reports as 2 reports and still will not pass the second id to the report. I teste this the only place where i am struck is the urlencode:( on pipe

Comment: Well I don't think you can do much there unfortunately